# How to start a web action from an imagebutton

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop an android app but I have some problems. I know a little bit about Java but I'm perfect with the XML part. I made an imagebutton and I want a browser to open a certain url when the user clicks on that button. Could someone please explain me how to do this step by step?

This is the button code taken from my main_activity.xml

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/donate"
    android:src="@drawable/donate"
    android:text="@string/about_link"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Please remember that im not very good at Java so I will just copy and paste to my activitymain.java

Comment: You're going to have a lot of trouble with Android if you don't know Java very well. I'd suggest learning the basics, then learning about the Android Intent system. That should get you moving in the right direction, but I don't think you'll have much success without learning Java. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Use this on imgebutton click listner**

```
webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);   
webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like that:

```
//any code

private ImageButton imageButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    //Only if you will use for something else
    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.donate);

    //any code
}

// any code

private void callBrowser(View view) {
    String url = "http://www.example.com";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
}

//any code
```

And inside your *xml* add this attribute:

```
android:onClick="callBrowser"
```